# Is there any way to create an UIVisualEffectView that doesn't lighten or darken what's behind it?

Tags: ios

I want to create a blur effect, but I only want to blur. I don't want to lighten or darken the content. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the alpha property of the UIVisualEffectView to get the result you wish. It worked for me.